# Keep git secret config files from being pushed

Tags: git, github

I have a file `secret.yml` which contains a few variables that should be kept secret:

```
token: SUPER-SECRET-TOKEN
another_secret_variable: abcdef
```

how can i make is so that when i push it, a template is pushed instead, like:

```
token: #INSERT YOUR TOKEN HERE
another_secret_variable: #INSERT YOUR SECRET VARIABLE HERE
```

Comment: If you just need to make sure your token doesn't get accidentally published, your best bet is to install a [`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and have it scan for the token. If it finds it, abort the commit with an error.

This one looks handy, clone it and modify it for your needs: https://github.com/niden/Git-Pre-Commit-Hook-for-certain-words

Comment: Don't include it in Git the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do it. If you want the file to be pushed to your remote repository, then it has to be tracked by git, and if git is tracking it, it will save any changes you make to it.

You can manually remove it from every commit (or manually stage every file except that one), but that would be a real pain.

The best way to go about doing what you are trying to do is probably to have a second file called `secret.yml.template` or something like that where you will have the template, and then in your README (or wherever you instruct users to add their tokens to `secret.yml) instruct them to change the name of the file to`secret.yml`.

Then you just add `secret.yml` to your `.gitignore` and everything should be good.

Answer (score 2):

the following is a possible solution. I'm not saying that it's great(see CAVEATS) but it works, I'd be happy to see something more worthy though.

You'd use git client-side hook for this.

Create a file called secret-template.yml and make sure it's gitignored

```
echo secret-template.yml >> .gitignore
```

create a file in `{projectRoot}/.git/hooks/pre-commit` with this contents

```
if [[ ! -f secret.yml ]] || [[ ! -f secret-template.yml ]]; then
    echo commit canceled. You should have both secret.yml and secret-template.yml in order to commit
    exit 1  
fi
mv secret.yml tmp_secret
cp secret-template.yml secret.yml
git add secret.yml
```

create a file in `{projectRoot}/.git/hooks/post-commit` with this contents

```
mv tmp_secret secret.yml
```

type this in your terminal

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit
```

you should be good to go

explanations:

pre-commit will run every time before you commit something, making sure you're committing your template instead of your secret.yml, so even if you did `git add secret.yml` it will override that adding the template instead. If either of these files don't exist the whole commit is canceled and you get a short message explaining why you're unable to commit

post-commit makes sure to leave your files as they were before your commit started (they'll run one after the other every time so it's not something you'll need to worry about)

`chmod +x` makes these files executable (it's a requirement for git hooks)

CAVEATS:
your git will permanently show that you have a modified file upon `git status`, it's the secret.yml file. This can be particularly annoying if you have a terminal prompt that constantly shows some git info (like branch, status, ...) like I do

Answer (score 0):

Creating an other file called template is a nice solution and if you whant to keep track of the original file too on the repository you can encrypt that file to make shure no one can read it. Leave the template unencrypted !!!

// Solution with git and .yml file
https://github.com/crohr/ebarnouflant/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

In addition of a [client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks)-based solution (which is brittle, as it can be bypassed), don't forget to activate server-side detection, in order to detect any secret file that might have still been pushed.

You now have (Q4 2022 / Q1 2023) on server side (github.com):

> ### [Secret scanning now push protects custom patterns](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-15-secret-scanning-now-push-protects-custom-patterns) (Dec. 2022)
>
> Previously, GitHub Advanced Security customers could enable push protection for all [patterns supported by default](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/secret-scanning-patterns#supported-secrets-for-push-protection).
>
> Now, admins can also enable [push protection for any custom pattern](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/defining-custom-patterns-for-secret-scanning) defined at the repository or organization level.
> Push protection for enterprise-level custom patterns will come in January.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/81782111/207498360-10037928-bd7b-4379-83db-16e234db4880.png?w=960&ssl=1 -- blocked custom pattern]
>
> - [Read our blog post to learn how you can push protect your custom patterns](https://github.blog/2022-12-15-github-advanced-security-customers-can-now-push-protect-their-custom-patterns)
> - [Learn how to secure your repositories with secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning)

And:

> ### [Secret scanning can now push protect enterprise-level custom patterns](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-04-secret-scanning-can-now-push-protect-enterprise-level-custom-patterns) (Jan. 2023)
>
> As of last month, GitHub Advanced Security customers can enable push protection for push protection for any custom pattern defined at the repository or organization level.
> Now, customers can also protect patterns that they've [defined at the enterprise level](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/defining-custom-patterns-for-secret-scanning#defining-a-custom-pattern-for-an-enterprise-account).

Finally:

> ### [Secret scanning’s push protection is available on public repositories, for free](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-05-09-secret-scannings-push-protection-is-available-on-public-repositories-for-free) (May. 2023)
>
> Secret scanning's push protection feature is now generally available for all free public repositories on GitHub.com.
>
> You can [enable push protection](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/protecting-pushes-with-secret-scanning#enabling-secret-scanning-as-a-push-protection) for any public repository on GitHub.com from your repository's "Code security and analysis" settings in the UI or [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/secret-scanning?apiVersion=2022-11-28).
> If you're an organization or enterprise owner, you can also also bulk-enable secret scanning.
>
> For your repositories that are not a part of an organization, you can bulk-enable secret scanning and push protection in your personal ["Code security and analysis" settings](https://github.com/settings/security_analysis).
>
> - **[Read our blog post](https://github.blog/2023-05-09-push-protection-is-generally-available-and-free-for-all-public-repositories)** to learn more about push protection's general availability
> - Learn more about protecting pushes [in our documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/protecting-pushes-with-secret-scanning) and share your feedback in our [community discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/54949)

---

Now with more AI...

> ### [Generate custom patterns for secret scanning with AI](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-08-generate-custom-patterns-for-secret-scanning-with-ai) (Nov. 2023)
>
> Secret scanning has a new, AI-powered regular expression generator for custom patterns.
> Within the existing custom patterns page, GitHub Advanced Security users can launch a generative AI experience where you input a text description of what pattern you would like to detect, include optional example strings that should be detected, and get matching regular expressions in return.
>
> The generator is in a limited beta and access will be granted through a [waitlist](https://github.com/features/preview/security).
>
> [image: https://github.com/courtneycl/cocotests-protected/assets/3474250/ccc9d2f6-2e21-49fa-abee-0e30f3771db3 -- screenshot of the regular expression generator]
>
> - [Sign up for the waitlist](https://github.com/features/preview/security)
> - [Learn more about secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/)
> - [Learn more about the regular expression generator for custom patterns](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/about-the-regular-expression-generator-for-custom-patterns)

---

> ### [Push protection is enabled for free users on GitHub](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-02-29-push-protection-is-enabled-for-free-users-on-github) (Feb. 2024)
>
> We’ve started the rollout for [enabling push protection](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-02-14-secret-scannings-push-protection-will-soon-be-enabled-for-all-free-accounts-on-github/) on all free user accounts on GitHub.
> This automatically protects you from accidentally committing secrets to public repositories, regardless of whether the repository itself has secret scanning enabled.
>
> If a secret is detected in any push to a public repository, your push will be blocked.
> You will have the option to remove the secret from your commits or, if you deem the secret safe, bypass the block.
>
> It might take a week or two for this change to apply to your account; you can verify status and opt-in early in your [code security and analysis settings](https://github.com/settings/security_analysis).
> Once enabled, you also have the option to opt-out.
> Disabling push protection may cause secrets to be accidentally leaked.
>
> - [Read the blog post](https://github.blog/2024-02-29-keeping-secrets-out-of-public-repositories/)
> - [Learn more about secret scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning)
> - [Learn more about push protection for users](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/secret-scanning/push-protection-for-users)
> - Join the discussion within [GitHub Community](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/110557)